# IF value = 'x' then substring

Tags: sql-server

I am looking to output the substring where country = 'us' only and leave the substring blank for all other countries. I have tried the below commented-out part but I am not sure my structure/logic is correct. Any help would be great

```
SELECT DISTINCT country,   ID, Name --, IF(country ='US', "SUBSTRING(ID, 3, 5)", " " ) AS substring
FROM TestTable
```

Comment: use [IIF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) or [CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Double quotes (`"`) are delimit identifiers for objects; `"SUBSTRING(ID, 3, 5)"` would try to reference a **column** in your table `TestTable` of that name.

Comment: Of course, the easiest way to test a piece of code is to run it; when you did run it what about the error or unexpected results/behaviour didn't you understand?

Comment: IIF is rewrited by sql server QO as CASE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Squirrel mentioned in the comments you can use `CASE` to fix your issue, the code then would look like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    country,
    ID,
    Name,
    CASE
        WHEN country = 'US' THEN SUBSTRING(ID, 3, 5)
        ELSE ''
    END AS substring
FROM TestTable
```